# field considered empty in FormRequest and validations

Tags: php, laravel

I have a template that allows adding new lines. Example: I want to add multiple products at once to a store, so I can add them all at once, through those lines that replicate themselves. The problem is that I need to validate these fields, they are all mandatory. I'm implementing so that I can walk through each one and leave it compulsory. However, I came across another problem, Laravel is telling me that my field is empty, but it is not. I would like to know how I can solve it, thank you in advance.

Here is my code to FormRequest

```
   public function rules()
    {        
        $rules = [];

        foreach($_POST['esp'] as $key => $esp){
            $name_field = "esp[" . $key . "]" . "[esprqe]"; //name of my field is complicated even as it is time based

            $rules[$name_field] = 'required';
     }                            
        return $rules;            
    }
```

My template is big, no need to show.

message I receive: esp[1553533952015][esprqe]: ["The esp[1553533952015][esprqe] field is required."]

My input is not empty, I do not know what the problem is

Answer (score 1):

You state the **name** of your field '`esprqe`' is **time based** and complicated.  This is likely the cause of your problem.

The `esp['.$key.']` field is probably fine, as this field is transferred from your form.  However, the value that goes into `esprqe`, if that is being generated in your server side code above (I don't know, you haven't provided how this field is generated), and if the rules are looking for that field to match a time-based generated field *on the form*... those values won't match and you will have a non-value coming into your method above.

This would very likely generate a message

> ["The esp[1553533952015][esprqe] field is required."]

If this is your issue, you can test by first creating a simple numbered index for the `esprqe` field that will be matched on both form and method.  If this succeeds, you can then increase the complexity using a **common** generator so that the rules section knows exactly what the name of the field is.  Time can't be common between form creation and rules creation - thus perhaps the reason for the failure.

Answer (score 0):

You need use "dot notation" to validate attributes within an array.

`$name_field = "esp.$key.esprqe";`

[Laravel Docs: validating arrays](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#validating-arrays)